# Datastructure to represent extensible and unique values

Tags: c#, enums

I've a small problem. I've a application monitoring part in a framework which is used by multiple applications.

Right now I've a functionality like this:

```
public enum Vars
{
   CPU,
   RAM
}

public void Add(Vars variable, object value)
{
   [...]
}
```

The Variable which is used as Parameter in the Add method will be used as the name of the entry in the database. 
Now I got the requirement, that applications can specify own variables outside the framework. Because you can't inherit from an enum this causes some trouble.

I see basicly 2 possibilities (which are bot not very satisfying in my opinion) to solve this.

Possibility 1:

```
public void Add(enum variable, object value)
```

This method would accept all sorts of enums, so users could use the Vars enums as well as enums which they've defined by themself. The problem with this solution: It would be possible, that users use the same names in both.. application and framework. I'm not able to differ between two enums with the value "CPU" (Framework may store percent values as "CPU", application may store process cpu usage as "CPU").

Possibility 2:

The second method would be an class instead a enum, something like:

```
public class Vars
{
    public const string CPU = "CPU";
    public const string RAM = "RAM";
}
```

The drawbacks here: 
1. More to write.
2. I would have to define parameters as strings:

```
public void Add(string variable, object value);
```

This could lead to missuse as well (Applications which add strings directly instead defining a class which inherits from Vars).

Any thoughts on how to define a model which:

- Can be inherited (to extend the values by applicationspecific values)
- Can be used as a parameter
- Ensures, that there are no double (=same value) entries
  ?

Comment: Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232488/emulate-enum-inheritance-best-choice-practices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context is not completely clear, but what about creating a class

```
public class Vars
{
    public static Vars CPU = Vars.Get("CPU", 1);
    public static Vars RAM = Vars.Get("RAM", 2);

    //You can keep one of the params, name or id
    private Vars(string name, int id)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static Vars Get(string name, int id)
    {
        //check if id or name exists in static dictionary, and return that instance or create new one
    }
}


public void Add(Vars variable, object value);
```

Now user can create any kind of Parameter and pass to the method,

```
Vars newVar = Vars.Get("MyNewParam", 10);
```

You can easily check if the passed param is one, about which you know

Get method returns same instance if the params are the same

Comment: You can also improve this snippet by adding a check for uniqueness in the constructor. Add a static `HashMap<string>` and add all `name` values there. If value already exists, an exception can be thrown.

Comment: @Impworks, I noticed that after post and already edited, thanks :)